# jquery append class with hover AND touch for mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm using the script below to add a class 'hover' to a div with the  class 'reveal-area'.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
   $(".reveal-area").hover(
      function () {
         $(this).addClass("reveal-show");
      },
      function () {
         $(this).removeClass("reveal-show");
      }
   );
});
```

This works fine on PC - but how can I add a function to include a touch activation (to append the class) on a mobile device? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```js
(function ($) {
 'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {

  //check device type
  function deviceType() {
   var mobile = false;
   //touch on IOS and Android
   var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
     var isMobile = /(mobile)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) || isAndroid || isMobile) {
    mobile = true;
   }else {
    mobile = false;
   }
   return mobile;
  }


  //desktop hover
  function itemHover() {
   $(".reveal-area").hover (
    function () {
     $(this).addClass("reveal-show");
    },
    function () {
     $(this).removeClass("reveal-show");
    }
   );
  }

  //mobile touch
      function itemTouch() {
        $(".reveal-area").on("touchstart", function () {
          $(".reveal-area").removeClass('reveal-show');
          $(this).addClass("reveal-show");
          
          //if you need working links comment this
          return false;
        });
      }

  function itemInit() {
   var mobile = deviceType();
   //check device type
   if(mobile == true) {
    //if mobile
    itemTouch();
   } else {
    //if desktop
    itemHover();
   }
  }

  //call function
  itemInit();

 });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.reveal-area {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.reveal-show {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hero-item">
        <div class="img-area">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="image alt"></div>
            <div class="reveal-area">
                <img src="link-here.png" class="reveal-button">
                <a href="/marine/" class="link-here">Text here...</a>
                <a href="/marine/" class="reveal-but">Learn more</a>
            </div> <!-- end reveal-area -->
          <div class="reveal-area">
                <img src="link-here.png" class="reveal-button">
                <a href="/marine/" class="link-here">Text here...</a>
                <a href="/marine/" class="reveal-but">Learn more</a>
            </div> <!-- end reveal-area -->
        </div> <!-- end hero item 1-->
    </div>
    <div class="hero-item">
        <div class="img-area">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="image alt"></div>
            <div class="reveal-area">
                <img src="link-here.png" class="reveal-button">
                <a href="/marine/" class="link-here">Text here...</a>
                <a href="/marine/" class="reveal-but">Learn more</a>
            </div> <!-- end reveal-area -->
          <div class="reveal-area">
                <img src="link-here.png" class="reveal-button">
                <a href="/marine/" class="link-here">Text here...</a>
                <a href="/marine/" class="reveal-but">Learn more</a>
            </div> <!-- end reveal-area -->
        </div> <!-- end hero item 1-->
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi - problem - the reveal-show containers have links! In your example, the div 'reveal-area reveal-show', slides up and displays a link (there are 6 separate 'reveal-area' containers). Therefore the mobile function's '$(this).toggleClass("reveal-show")' means you can't touch the link. I've changed it to '$(this).addClass("reveal-show")' which is OK - but I need a way to remove the 'reveal-show' class when I touch any one of the other 6 'reveal' containers ...somethink like '.not(this)removeClass'. (so that more than one 'reveal-area' can never be open) But I don't know how to do this! thanks

Comment: Give me please your HTML and I will help you.

Comment: Edit didn't work - here is html, 6 of these:<div class="hero-item">
  <div class="img-area"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image alt"></div>
   <div class="reveal-area">
     <img src="link-here.png" class="reveal-button">
    <a href="/marine/" class="link-here">Text here...</a>
     <a href="/marine/" class="reveal-but">Learn more</a>
    </div> <!-- end reveal-area -->
  </div> <!-- end hero item 1-->

Comment: Edited, please check if it what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by identifying the screen width and attaching an event listener to you class `.reveal-area`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 480) { //change this value for your convenience
        $(".reveal-area").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("reveal-show");
        })
    }

    $(".reveal-area").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("reveal-show");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use touchstart function
$('.reveal-area').on("touchstart", function (e) {
     'use strict'; //satisfy code inspectors
   var link = $(this); //preselect the link
   if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
     return true;
      $(this).addClass("reveal-show");
   } 
  else {
  link.addClass('hover');
  $('.reveal-area').not(this).removeClass('hover');
    e.preventDefault();
     $(this).removeClass("reveal-show");
    return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent     
    return points
  }
});

$('ul li.has-children').on("touchstart", function (e) {
  'use strict'; //satisfy code inspectors
   var link = $(this); //preselect the link
   if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
     return true;
   } 
  else {
  link.addClass('hover');
  $('ul > li').not(this).removeClass('hover');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent     
    return points
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dhaarani - but i'm not sure how to implement this to <div class="reveal-area"> so that on mobile devices, on touch, this div changes to <div class="reveal-area hover"> . Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
$(".reveal-area").click(
    $(this).toggleClass("reveal-show");
});
```